# How do I access Cassandra configuration from the Java driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

How do I read Cassandra configuration in Java like the **Data Directory location**.
I could not find  the Data Directory location in: Configuration, Host or Metadata property. 
I would have thought you would be bale to read all the properties in the yaml file.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone can help with this?

Comment: If it is not possible and you are not getting a response, then maybe you are attempting something that is unusual. Why would client code be concerned about the data directory location of a C* node? And of which node of the cluster your code connects to?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Server-side configuration is not exposed to the drivers/clients. Cheers!